# Putting Frame over UserForm but background doesnt match

Tags: excel, vba

I have a frame via userform and i have set both the same background so that frame looks like it is transparent (because vba does not support transparent frames) but the transition is very different between userform and frame. Is it possible to correct this in VBA?

[image: My Image here]

I want the transition between the frame and the background of the UserForm to be seamless

Comment: Please show how the backcolor of the userform is declared.  It looks like you have a gradient in that definition.

Comment: Using `Me.Frame1.BackColor = Me.BackColor` sets the backcolor of the frame to exactly the backcolor of the form. However, your screenshot looks odd - it looks as if the form has a gradient background, and I don't know about a way to have a gradient as backcolor on VBA forms - except by setting a background image.

Comment: yes it is a gradient backcolor, I created a form in power point and with gradian color and added to userform and frame. So for gradient colors, its not possible to make a smooth transition between frame and userform?

Comment: Maybe this would help:  https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/how-to-make-userform-frame-controls-transparent.1012664/